# Determining if $x\left(t\right)$ is real with Fourier series?

Tags: fourier-series

The question states that $x\left(t\right)$ has Fourier coefficients $a_k=\{x, k=0; j\left(\frac 1 2\right)^{|k|},k\neq0$.  I am to determine whether $x\left(t\right)$ is real.

Here is what I've done so far:
For $x\left(t\right)$ to be real, $a_k=a_{-k}^*$ must hold true.
$a_{k,k\neq0}=j\left(\frac12\right)^{|k|}\neq a_{-k,k\neq0}^*=-j\left(\frac12\right)^{|-k|}=-j\left(\frac12\right)^{|k|}$
So, $x\left(t\right)\notin\Bbb R$

Is that correct?  I feel like there is some incorrect assumption I made somewhere in there.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: So $j$ is the phycist's $i$, right? Then you are correct.

Comment: @julien yup, thank you!

Comment: Note you should probably write $\bar{a_k}$ rather than $a_k^*$. Unless this is some other physicist's notation I don't know of.

Comment: @julien It's the adjoint of a $1\times 1$ matrix.

Comment: @julien - $j$ is used as $\sqrt{-1}$ only in electrical engineering. Real physicists just use $i$.

Comment: @5pm Which is most commonly denoted by $\bar{a_k}$, no? I should have said convention rather than notation.

Comment: @nbubis Ah, ok. Thanks for the note.

Comment: @nbubis I'm a student studying electrical engineering, so that would be why I used $j$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct, as julien already said. Additional remark: if you factor $j$ out, then the rest is a symmetric series with real coefficients. Therefore, $x$ is $j$ times a real function, i.e., a purely imaginary function.